# Get only the string of the error from ValidationMessage in blazor?

Tags: blazor, asp.net-blazor, blazor-editform

While using blazor's `ValidationMessage` I realized that this component wraps the error around a `div` and add the class `validation-message`

[image]

How can I get only the error string without the div?

Answer (score 1):

You can get validation error messages from [`EditContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.editcontext?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditContext);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=aspnetcore-3.1)

```cs
<EditForm @ref="_editForm">
...
</EditForm>
@code {
    private EditForm _editForm;
    protected void OnInitialized()
    {
        var editContext = _editForm.EditContext;
        editContext.OnValidationStateChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
             var validationMessages = editContext.GetValidationMessages();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I remove this on dispose?